# Why does it say java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption when the last int array is entered?

Tags: java, arrays

First I had skipping the Employee's Name part so I added k.nextLine to consume the \n before.
Now I have this:

DISCOUNT SUPERMALL

[Sales Report]

Enter number of Employee: 3

Employee Name:    A

Employee's Sales: 1

Employee Name:    S

Employee's Sales: 2

Employee Name:    D

Employee's Sales: 3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Case_Study.main(Case_Study.java:22)
```

Heres what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {   Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("DISCOUNT SUPERMALL");
    System.out.println(" [Sales Report]");
    System.out.print("Enter number of Employee: ");
    int numberOfEmp = k.nextInt();
    String[] empName = new String [numberOfEmp];
    double[] empSale = new double [numberOfEmp];

    for(int a=0; a<numberOfEmp; a++)
    {   System.out.print("Employee Name:    ");
        k.nextLine();
        empName[a] = k.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Employee's Sales: ");
        empSale[a] = k.nextDouble();
    }   System.out.println();


    for (int c=0; c<numberOfEmp; c++)
    {   System.out.println("Name:  "+empName[numberOfEmp]);
        System.out.println("Sales: "+empSale[numberOfEmp]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the array is of size `3`, the last possible index you can use is `2` (`3-1`) because indexing starts from 0.

Comment: Should just use this: `System.out.println("Name:  "+empName[ (numberOfEmp >= 1) ? (numberOfEmp-1) : 0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final loop replace:

```
System.out.println("Name:  "+empName[numberOfEmp]);
```

with

```
System.out.println("Name:  "+empName[c]);
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, when you create your `empName` array, you are creating it of size `numberOfEmp`. Because the array is 0 indexed, you can use numbers `0` thru `(numberOfEmp - 1)`. If you take the example of 6 employees you are setting `numberOfEmp` to 6 so the arrays has valid indexes for `0-5`. When you used `empName[numberOfEmp]` you would be doing `empName[6]` which is outside of the bounds of the array which stops at 5, hence the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption